# Synaptic Package Manager & Software Manager Not Opening

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, package-management, upgrade, cinnamon

In Linux Mint 17, when I try to open Synaptic Package Manager or Software Manager from the gui, the popup appears to enter my password.  Yet when I enter it correctly, nothing happens; neither window opens.  When I run synaptic from terminal, this is the output:

```
user@hostname ~ $ sudo synaptic
[sudo] password for user: 
No protocol specified

** (synaptic:4516): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.

(synaptic:4516): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

Does anybody know how I could fix this?